# Rotate + into a X and back again?

Tags: android

I have the following view:

[image]

I'm trying to, on tap, rotate it 45 degrees such that it becomes a X, at the moment i'm trying to use two Animators, one with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="45"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="200"
    android:startOffset="0"
    />
```

and the other

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toDegrees="45"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="200"
    android:startOffset="0"
    />
```

and finally in a simple toggle logic:

```
    if(isPlus){
        rotation_cross.setRepeatCount(0);
        rotation_cross.setFillEnabled(true);
        rotation_cross.setFillAfter(true);
        mFab.startAnimation(rotation_cross);
    }
    else{
        rotation_plus.setRepeatCount(0);
        rotation_plus.setFillEnabled(true);
        rotation_plus.setFillAfter(true);
        mFab.startAnimation(rotation_plus);
   }
```

Sadly, all that seems to happen is that it jumps forward than goes backward, here is a video to show it in action:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQ4684sq01M&feature=youtu.be

I've tried every combination of rotation numbers i can think of! Please assist!

Comment: Which xml is your rotate plus?

Comment: @ZaidDaghestani the first one

Comment: Strange.
i just tested on my end and it works fine:

Comment: what android are you running?